# My concerns about the tag 'nazi-germany'

Tags: discussion

This is a meta post, but I have less then 5 reputation, so I cannot on meta.

I am German and in my opinion `Nazi-germany` might be historically correct, but it sounds that Germany and Nazis are still connected. And `Nazi-Germany` is "easier to say" than `National-Socialism-in-Germany`

I would prefer to rename the tag to `nazi` or `historic-Germany` or `Germany-during-ww2` or `National-Socialism-in-Germany`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

IMO the tag serves its purpose. "Nazi Germany" is a well understood term to describe an important period in German history under the Nazis. Once you're here a bit more, you'll find this hasn't been a source of confusion (examples on History.SE where it was are welcome). What has been is people coming in with an agenda to cause confusion, those are quickly downvoted and/or deleted. This is a general problem with any controversial historical topics.

As to the proposed tags, they are not synonyms.

- `nazi` or `National-Socialism` can be from any period and not specific to Germany.
- `historic-germany` spans the entire history of Germany.
- `germany-during-ww2` does not cover the whole of the Nazi regime which existed prior to WW2.

Another attempt might be `germany-under-the-nazis` but this implies the Nazis conquered or occupied Germany rather than being the (arguably) legitimate government. Compare, for example, `france-under-the-nazis`.

Each tag has a short and long description to avoid just this sort of confusion. [Here is `nazi-germany`'s](https://history.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/271) short description at the time of this writing.

> The period of German history from 1933 - 1945, specifically regarding the rise of the National Socialist German Workers Party.

[Maybe you can improve it](https://history.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/271)?

Comment: It's common sense that not everyone was a nazi, any more than everyone was a bourbon in bourbon france!

Comment: Note that the typical term for the previous regime is "Weimar Germany" (or "Weimar Republic" with the "Germany" understood), and "German Empire" before that. In other words, the scheme is to associate the era with the ruling regime the country was being run under at the time. So there's nothing really special about the "Nazi" there, other than that a lot of people today really don't like Nazis.

Answer (score 13):

As a German, I hold the exact opposite view. To me, the tag [nazi-germany](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nazi-germany) means that it's sufficiently distanced from the distinct tag [germany](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/germany). It's a very specific time-frame and history episode, so it exists as a separate tag as compared to just tagging it [germany](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/germany) and [nazi](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nazi), which puts it close to all the other questions about the lighter side of German history.

Comment: And that's an important point too. Since this is a *history* stack, Almost by definition our tags are about things that no longer exist. There are exceptions, but they are just that, exceptions.

Comment: To extend what you and @T.E.D. (in a comment to another answer) mentioned, linking time periods and/or rulers with their associated country to describe an era/regime is common all over. For example, you can speak of Medieval England, the British Raj of India, Ancien Regime France versus Republican France, Imperial Russia versus Soviet Russia versus Modern Russia, Pharaonic Egypt versus Roman Egypt versus Ottoman Egypt, etc.

Answer (score 3):

As an analogy, I would point out that there is a tag for *British-Empire*. **Theoretically**, there never was a "British Empire" as such - British monarchs from Victoria to George VI were Empress/Emperor of **India**, but nowhere else. However, the term *British Empire* is widely understood to mean Britain's hegemony during a particular period of history, so is useful. From 21st Century perspective, much of what was done in the name of British imperialism is utterly unacceptable, but that is historically irrelevant. It happened, we can only attempt to understand it.

Comment: I don't think British Empire is connected to something negative

Comment: @Motte001 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-imperialism

Comment: @called2voyage the article you linked is more general. You always have groups disliking the current government

Comment: @Motte001 "I don't think British Empire is connected to something negative "  I think Gandhi *et al* would probably disagree.

Comment: @TheHonRose This is a good example of the aphorism that history is written by the victors.

Comment: @TheHonRose you're right